# Should I include <vector> even though it is already included by <regex> for example or others?

Tags: c++, c++11

Should I include `<vector>` even though it is already included by `<regex>` for example or others?

I have a `<regex>` include, which seems to include `<vector>` also, so I don't have to
include `<vector>`. Is it considered better style to explicitly include `<vector>` anyway?

Comment: You should not assume vector is included by other headers. So yes, you should include it.

Comment: Actually I think @juanchopanza already gave all the answer needed

Comment: @juanchopanza just make that an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Which standard library headers include which other standard library headers is an implementation detail you should not rely on.

If you need certain headers in your code, include them when you use them. Otherwise compiling your code on other compiler and/or library versions may result in errors.

Technically, your code is ill-formed if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should include vector - the fact that regex includes vector is compiler dependent and may change at any time

Comment: "at any time". Depending on the moon cycle, or solar flares `;-)`

Comment: @rubenvb Good old`#pragma gibbous`

Comment: @Yakk call me silly but do you have a reference for that? My google-joke-fu is failing.

Comment: gibbous, as in gibbous moon.  Implying that there is a `#pragma` that does something contingent on the phase of the moon (none such exist). @rubenvb